# Query select all lucene java

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, document, query-parser

I'm trying to do query with Lucene and I would like to select the documents whose title begins with the "@" character .
I looked at the documentation but the results is zero elements.
This is the code and the result.
Thanks for your help.

this is the code:

```
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
addDoc(w, "@aa Lucene in Action", "193398817");
addDoc(w, "@ba Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
addDoc(w, "prova Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
w.close();
String querystring = "@";

Query q;
q = new QueryParser(LUCENE_41, "title", new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_41)).parse(querystring);
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, 1000000);

ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
}

reader.close();
```

and this is the output

```
Building provaLucerne 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ provaLucerne ---
Found 0 hits.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.505s
Finished at: Wed Nov 02 19:49:39 CET 2016
Final Memory: 5M/155M
```

Comment: <version>4.1.0</version>

Comment: I guess `@` are removed by the `StandardAnalyzer` while indexing

Answer (score 0):

You are using StandardAnalyzer which uses StandardTokenizer.  "@" character is among the set of token-splitting punctuation, in standard Toeknizer.

so the string "@aa Lucene in Action"
is tokenized into "aa","Lucene","in","Action" tokens.

You can use KeywordAnalyzer or WhitespaceAnalyzer and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: i have change 
        q = new QueryParser(LUCENE_41, "title", new WhitespaceAnalyzer(LUCENE_41)).parse(querystring);

but the result is always 0

Comment: in ypur queryString can you try '@*' instead "@"

Comment: also try searching for "@aa" and see if that returns anything

Comment: the firt return 0 result and the second return right, but i have to analize a file with many "title" that begin with "@". at this point I think I'll change my query, but with lucene how does the "select all" ?

Comment: the first one did you try with single quote or double quotes ? if with single quotes can you try this "@*". Also you can take a look at PrefixQuery in lucene.

Comment: make sure that you drop your old indexes first and that you use the same analyzer while indexing otherwise it won't work

Comment: now it works, I did not realize that I had not changed the analyzer when insert texts in doc.
but now how can I do a "select all"?

Comment: what do you mean by select all ? did "@*"  not give you all the documents starting with "@"